# Is there a n-category structure on algebras for $e_n$-like operads?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, higher-category-theory, operads

I'm fishing in troubled waters here and therefore the question is vague and meant to be as general as possible. In particular "$e_n$-like operad" can be an algebraic or topological $e_n$ operad, as for example the topological little n-cubes, or the algebraic operad that encodes homotopy Poisson-n algebras over various base fields.

So the question is then, if there is any known structure of an n-category, or $(\infty,n)$-category on a (subset of) algebras for such an operad, that is naturally induced from that operad.

Comment: Are you familiar with the work of Haugseng?  https://arxiv.org/abs/1412.8459v2

Comment: Not yet, but the abstract sounds interesting.

Comment: A perhaps more elementary thing to say is that an (oo, n)-category with one object, one 1-morphism, ..., one (n-1)-morphism is an E_n-algebra in spaces.